# Error ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when accessing gitlab server url in browser or wget command

Tags: networking, gitlab, vpn

I'm having this error (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)  when I try to acess a gitlab on-premise server in the browser, and when I try wget http://172.16.50.2:8090/ in linux terminal, It says:

--2021-07-23 17:00:45--  http://172.16.50.2:8090/
Connecting-to 172.16.50.2:8090... **connected**.
HTTP request was sent, waiting for response... No data received.
Trying again.

Based on the wget output, I belive It isn't been blocked by the firewall, but It's been blocked by some gitlab configuration, anyone can help me giving me any direction, or other adivices that will help me to debug this problem.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, It was a conflit portfoward rule in the firewall!!!